# Web Browser API in Java that works

Tags: java, browser

I am trying to make a web browser in java. I have tried with this code, it works but the page appears blue

```
private JEditorPane display;
display.setPage("https://www.google.se");
```

Tried with "Lobo-Browser" it does not work. Please do not suggest premium APIs like "JxBrowser". I am looking for a free web browser API that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea JDIC, but ofc there are   many more others, you should find one suited for you... depends on what do you expect from it.

http://workshop.evolutionzone.com/2007/08/30/jdic-embedding-a-web-browser-in-java/